# ARA framework Nested micro-frontend

Tags: vue.js, nested, nuxt.js, ara

I'm discovering ARA framework.

I'm in the process of setting up an SSR architecture based on Nuxt.js as the host application to aggregate micro-frontend
I configured the Nova proxy and declared each of my micro-frontends in the Nova cluster
I achieve independently in Nuxt.js each of the micro-frontend in SSR or in client-side

My problem is that I want to nest some micro-frontend together
To be clearer, I have a micro-frontend for a library of UI components that I want to use through the other micro-frontends (for example a cart management or a magazine) and call in Nuxt.js only these
In this case, my first micro-frontend level mounts well in Nuxt.js but the UI kit doesn't

Could you guide me on something that I didn't understand or did wrong?

Thks

Comment: Let me check if I understand... You're using Nuxt.js to load micro-frontends applications. And you are handling it OK, but you want to treat you UI lib as micro-frontend, so all of your micro-frontend applications don't have to carry it in it's bundles, so your main Nuxt.js application load it for them and they just use it.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Almost!

I wish every micro-frontend could use components from the UI library that itself is a micro-frontend

So for example, I'm doing a Cart micro-frontend that loads <Nova> tags from the UI micro-frontend Kit
Nuxt.js will only have to load the Cart micro-frontend and everything is well rendered